# How to change the color of an axis title in matplotlib after setting the title?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wanted to plot a function on a black colored background. I already managed to modify the labels etc. but I don't know the command to change the color of the title solely.

Example

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

fig1.patch.set_facecolor('k')     
ax1.set_facecolor('k')
ax1.xaxis.label.set_color('w')
ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('w')
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color('w')
ax1.spines['top'].set_color('w')
ax1.spines['left'].set_color('w')
ax1.spines['right'].set_color('w')
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', colors='w')


x=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
ax1.plot(x, np.exp(x))
ax1.set_title('This title\'s color should be modified afterwards', color='w')
```

I need this for a GUI I created. I don't want to change the rcParams of the matplotlib module. I want to enter a command similar to above.

[image: Example]

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You code can change the color of title.

Comment: This is only an example. I have coded another script where the title includes relevant info, but I want to change the color of the title, e.g. to blue.

Comment: `ax1.set_title('This title\'s color should be modified afterwards', color='blue')` works for me

Comment: Obviously, but the title is generated automatically and includes variables that were calculated and aren’t saved in a separate variable. Is there a way to change it without reentering the title, so I don’t need to recalculate the quantities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `set_color` method:

```
ax1.title.set_color('blue')
```

Comment: Thank you, sometimes the solution is so simple, but it is so hard to find the correct method among the numerous amount of methods.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following what you want?

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

title = 'This title'
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

fig1.patch.set_facecolor('k')     
ax1.set_facecolor('k')
ax1.xaxis.label.set_color('w')
ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('w')
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color('w')
ax1.spines['top'].set_color('w')
ax1.spines['left'].set_color('w')
ax1.spines['right'].set_color('w')
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', colors='w')
x=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
ax1.plot(x, np.exp(x))
ax1.set_title(title+'\'s color should be modified afterwards', color='blue')
```

[image]